MockedStatic: Wanted but not invoked Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock
I'm running into some trouble with Mockito's MockedStatic where despite my static method getting called (verified by putting debug print statements) with correct arguments, Mockito is still complaining
Here's my subject code
import com.company.project.bo.requests.MyRequest;
import com.company.project.bo.responses.MyResponse;
import com.company.project.util.LoggingHelper;

class MySubjectClass {
    ..
    // this is the entry-point function
    public MyResponse enact(final MyRequest request) {
        logInputs(request);
        ..
    }

    private void logInputs(final MyRequest request) {
        ..
        // I verified by adding debug print statements here to verify
        // that indeed this is getting invoked (with correct arguments)
        LoggingHelper.recordEntityId(request.getEntityId());
        ..
    }
..
}

Here's my unit-test:
import com.company.project.bo.EntityId;
import com.company.project.bo.responses.MyResponse;
import com.company.project.util.LoggingHelper;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.MockedStatic;

class TestMySubjectClass {
    private static final EntityId ENTITY_ID = EntityId.of("XYZ0123PQR789LMN");
    private final MyClass subject = new MyClass(); // subject: object of class under test
    ..

    @Test
    public void myTestMethod() {
        ..
        final MyResponse response = subject.enact(request);
        try (final MockedStatic<LoggingHelper> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(LoggingHelper.class)) {
            ..
            mockedStatic.verify(() -> LoggingHelper.recordEntityId(ENTITY_ID.value()));
            mockedStatic.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
        }   
    }
}

Here's the error I'm getting:
Wanted but not invoked:
LoggingHelper.class.recordEntityId(
    "XYZ0123PQR789LMN"
);
-> at com.company.project.util.LoggingHelper.recordEntityId(LoggingHelper.java:214)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.


The puzzling bit is that same mockedStatic implementation is working just fine in other test-methods within this class, just failing for this one particular test-case.
Where am I going wrong?


My bad. I was invoking my method-under-test outside the MockedStatic try-block
After moving the invocation (that triggers the entire function being unit-tested) inside try-block, it started passing

Wrong
..
final MyResponse response = subject.enact(request); // this was placed outside try-block
try (final MockedStatic<LoggingHelper> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(LoggingHelper.class)) {
    ..
    mockedStatic.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
}

Correct
..
try (final MockedStatic<LoggingHelper> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(LoggingHelper.class)) {
    final MyResponse response = subject.enact(request); // it was supposed to be inside try-block
    ..
    mockedStatic.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
}

